# Ruby unexpected kEND, expecting $end

Tags: ruby

```
require 'open-uri'
print "Enter a URL"
add = gets
open(#{add}) do |f|
  j = f.read.scan(/<img/)
  jlen = j.length
  puts jlen
end
```

Is the code I have.
For some reason, ruby is giving me the error:`findimages.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected kEND, expecting $end`
Why is this?

Comment: That error means "I was looking through your source code, and I expected to see the end of the file, but I found an `end` instead."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`#{}` works only inside interpolated strings. Use `open(add)` (or perfectly correct, but perfectly unnecessary `open("#{add}")`).

Answer (score 4):

On this line:

```
open(#{add}) do |f|
```

You are trying to use `#{}` to interpolate a variable into a string, but outside of a string. The `#` is being interpreted as the start of the comment, and the rest of the line is treated as a comment.

You can just use `add` directly here, without any string interpolation.

Comment: I do find it a little odd that the lexer was looking for `$end` instead of a right paren.

Comment: @Phrogz When I tested this out with a similar program, I got an error about the missing paren, and an error about `$end`. I am assuming that the first error gets the parser confused, and so the second error is spurious.